# I want my html page to redirect to another html page when I submit a certain input how can i do that

Tags: javascript, php, html

**strong text**
I need the html page to go to another page when i submit a certain input

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via HTML forms.
you need to use the action(where you want to redirect page) and method(GET,POST) attribute in form.
for example

```
<form action="www.example.com" method="post">
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

on clicking submit it will redirect to the URL given in the action attribute.

Comment: i cant thank you enough. You just saved my life

Comment: but can the website the html page redirects to be decided by the text input. like example if i search for xyz it should take me to a website but if i search for abc it takes me to a different website

Comment: for that, I think you should refer to this website (https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/submit-button-action-based-on-different-conditions/7227). you can do all that using javascript/jquery also.